# Entity Framework related entities generate unnecessary joins of the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am running into issue of EF Core 3.1 generating multiple `INNER JOIN`s to the same table even though it has enough information to avoid it.

Simplified model with mapping :

```
internal class PRecord
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public PImport Import { get; private set; }

    private PRecord()
    {
    }

    internal PRecord(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public class PRecordDbMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PRecord>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PRecord> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("p_records");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            builder.Property<long>("PImportId").HasColumnName("p_import_id");

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Import).WithMany(x => x.Records).HasForeignKey("PImportId").IsRequired();
        }
    }
}

internal class PImport
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public PSource Source { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<PRecord> Records { get; private set; }

    private PImport()
    {
    }

    internal PImport(PSource source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    public class PImportDbMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PImport>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PImport> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("p_imports");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            builder.Property<int>("PSourceId").HasColumnName("p_source_id");

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Source).WithMany(x => x.Imports).HasForeignKey("PSourceId").IsRequired();
        }
    }
}

internal class PSource
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public PImport CurrentImport { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<PImport> Imports { get; private set; }

    private PSource()
    {
    }

    internal PSource(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public class PSourceDbMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PSource>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PSource> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("p_sources");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            builder.Property<long>("CurrentPImportId").HasColumnName("current_p_import_id");

            builder.HasOne(x => x.CurrentImport).WithOne().HasForeignKey<PEPSource>("CurrentPImportId");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple variants of the following, but with slight variations I always get the same problem in SQL :

```
var query = ctx.PRecords
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("bla"))
               .Where(x => x.Import.Source.CurrentImport == x.Import)
               .Select(x => new { Record = x, Source = x.Import.Source });

SELECT 
    [p].[id], [p].[name], [p].[p_import_id], [p1].[id], [p1].[current_p_import_id]
FROM [p_records] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [p_source_imports] AS [p0] ON [p].[p_import_id] = [p0].[id]
INNER JOIN [p_sources] AS [p1] ON [p0].[p_source_id] = [p1].[id]
INNER JOIN [p_source_imports] AS [p2] ON [p1].[current_p_import_id] = [p2].[id]
WHERE (CHARINDEX(N'bla', [p].[name]) > 0) AND ([p2].[id] = [p0].[id])
```

I am able to generate the SQL I want with the following code :

```
var query = ctx.PSources
               .Where(x => x.CurrentImport != null)
               .SelectMany(x => x.CurrentImport.Records, (x, y) => new { Record = y, Source = x })
               .Where(x => x.Record.Name.Contains("bla"));
```

The issue with this one is that I want to move the `.Where(x => x.Record.Name.Contains("bla"))` into extension method. And in this query I have to apply it on the anonymous type.

So I have two questions :

1. Can the first query be salvaged to generate reasonable SQL, while still returning `IQueryable<PRecord>` or if not possible a queryable of some non-anonymous type ?
2. If (1) cannot be achieved reasonably, can I achieve the moving of the WHERE condition on the Name to some extension method anyway?

EDIT: specified EF Core 3.1 as the verswion used

EDIT: the accepted solution is enough for my case. Completely clean solution might not be possible in the current version of EF Core. As I was browsing github issues for EF Core it seems the SQL generator might have restrictions that cause the more straightforward queries to use unnecessary 'JOIN's.

So the query I went with is :

```
var query = ctx.PSources
               .Where(x => x.CurrentImport != null)
               .SelectMany(x => x.CurrentImport.Records, (x, y) => new SourceRecordPair() { Record = y, Source = x })
               .Where(x => x.Record.Name.Contains("bla"));
```

Comment: @marc_s Sorry for the out-of-topic question, but is there some agreed upon formatting of code/SQL, because your changes to the Linq code I would have never written them this way :) Thanks for the rest of the changes.

Comment: Those are my own personal "best practices" of making code look consistent and clear - and I've had overwhelmingly positive feedback from SO users liking this style. But it's not an "official" SO style or anything

Comment: edited to include the version

Comment: @GertArnold that unfortunately does not change the query, that was how I originally had it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass anonymous types from one method to the other and still access the properties.  You will need to strongly type the following:

```
new SomeModel { Record = y, Source = x })
```

Comment: Your first suggestion solves it. I somehow assumed that it will not allow me to use constructor of custom type in the Linq code. But it just does not allow constructors with parameters, parameterless constructor with initialization is allowed. It is not ideal solution - the extension method now needs to work on the new type even though it needs just the PRecord. 
I will accept your answer, but in the second part of your answer I think that the FilterBlah does something rather different than the original query is doing, so if I am correct, can you edit it out so as to not confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can the first query be salvaged to generate reasonable SQL, while still returning `IQueryable<PRecord>` or if not possible a queryable of some non-anonymous type ?

Yes, by breaking the encapsulation and accessing directly the shadow FK property (with `EF.Property` method) inside the query. Error prone (you need to know/keep in sync the property name `string`), but can be used as workaround until gets fixed by EF Core (because it's current EF Core defect):

```
.Where(x => EF.Property<long?>(x.Import.Source, "CurrentPImportId") == x.Import.Id)
```

> 2. If (1) cannot be achieved reasonably, can I achieve the moving of the WHERE condition on the Name to some extension method anyway?

Yes. But you have to create two extension methods - one normal and one generic with expression argument for extracting the "source", e.g.

```
public static IQueryable<PRecord> FilterRecords(this IQueryable<PRecord> source)
    => source.FilterRecords(x => x);

public static IQueryable<T> FilterRecords<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, PRecord>> recordSelector)
    => source.Where(recordSelector.Apply(
            x => x.Name.Contains("blah") // actual filter goes here
        ));
```

Now you can use the non generic method with your first query

```
var query = ctx.PRecords
    .FilterRecords() // <--
    .Where(x => EF.Property<long?>(x.Import.Source, "CurrentPImportId") == x.Import.Id) // from (1)
    .Select(x => new { Record = x, Source = x.Import.Source });
```

and the generic method with your second query

```
var query = ctx.PSources
    .Where(x => x.CurrentImport != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x.CurrentImport.Records, (x, y) => new { Record = y, Source = x })
    .FilterRecords(x => x.Record); // <--
```

Note that the generic method works with any type of `T`, and also the `T` is inferred by the compiler, so you can use it with both anonymous and concrete type projections.

The first method will simply call the second passing "self selector" (`x => x`), and the actual implementation will be in the second method. With the following detail - you need a small helper utility for composing expressions, so the `Apply` method here is from my own `ExpressionUtils` helper class which I use in many expression related answers:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> Apply<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> outer, Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> inner)
        => Expression.Lambda<Func<TOuter, TResult>>(inner.Body.ReplaceParameter(inner.Parameters[0], outer.Body), outer.Parameters);

    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> ApplyTo<TInner, TResult, TOuter>(this Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> inner, Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> outer)
        => outer.Apply(inner);

    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { source = source, target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public Expression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == source ? target : node;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using magic strings. As for the extension method, I did the generic version you showed here. Though because of some mental block I did not realize that I can use it also on anonymous types.